# Text output from other programs in Powershell contain unwanted spaces between characters

Tags: powershell, format, output

I would like to work with (text)output from other programs in Powershell, but all the time I am getting this weird format with unwanted whitespaces between every character.

For example, when running:

```
&"C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore\aacinfo.exe" report
```

It produces output like:

```
Subscribing for reports, press any key to stop...


Reporting on point-product 12dd49a3-c20f-4636-b638-fc9ce8c76735
Waiting for events for point-product ProductTracker...

Reporting on point-product 4562a25a-895d-4e20-bb47-7317801f0108
Waiting for events for point-product ProductTracker...
```

and so so... it is a continuous stream until the program is stopped.

When I try to save it to a file with:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore\aacinfo.exe" report | out-file -encoding utf8 C:\temp\output.log
```

The file content looks like this:

```
S u b s c r i b i n g   f o r   r e p o r t s ,   p r e s s   a n y   k e y   t o   s t o p . . . 
 
 
 
 
 
 R e p o r t i n g   o n   p o i n t - p r o d u c t   1 2 d d 4 9 a 3 - c 2 0 f - 4 6 3 6 - b 6 3 8 - f c 9 c e 8 c 7 6 7 3 5 
 
 W a i t i n g   f o r   e v e n t s   f o r   p o i n t - p r o d u c t   P r o d u c t T r a c k e r . . . 
 
 
 
 R e p o r t i n g   o n   p o i n t - p r o d u c t   4 5 6 2 a 2 5 a - 8 9 5 d - 4 e 2 0 - b b 4 7 - 7 3 1 7 8 0 1 f 0 1 0 8 
 
 W a i t i n g   f o r   e v e n t s   f o r   p o i n t - p r o d u c t   P r o d u c t T r a c k e r . . .
```

Why is that and how to avoid all those additional spaces between the characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like **`aacinfo.exe` unexpectedly outputs *UTF-16LE*-encoded text** instead of using the character encoding specified by the current console's code page (as reflected in the output from `chcp`).

Because **PowerShell** expects the latter, it ***misinterprets* `aacinfo.exe`'s output**, which explains your symptom.

- In short: What **appear to be extra *spaces*** - e.g. in Notepad - are **actually `NUL` characters** (characters with code point `0x0`) that result from the mistaken interpretation of the UTF-16 bytes as *individual* characters, so that each `0x0` byte that makes up one half of a *two-byte sequence* encoding an ASCII-range character mistakenly becomes a character in its own right.

The **solution** is to - temporarily - set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to UTF-16LE (`[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode`), which instructs PowerShell to use that encoding for decoding `aacinfo.exe`'s output:

```bash
$prev = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode

& 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore\aacinfo.exe' report | 
  Out-File -Encoding utf8 C:\temp\output.log

[Console]::OutputEncoding = $prev
```

Note:

- In ***Windows PowerShell* and [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.3.x*, PowerShell *invariably* decodes output from external programs *into .NET strings*** before processing it further, even when using `>`, the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).
- In PowerShell **v7.4+** **`>` is now capable of passing the *raw byte stream* of an external program's stdout output through to a file** (whereas the decoding into strings still happens if you use `Out-File` explicitly).

  - This not only speeds up I/O redirection with external programs but also prevents potential mistinterpretation.
  - That said, capturing raw *UTF-16LE* data, specifically, will only result in a well-formed file if the byte stream *starts with a BOM*, which is *not* typical for to-stdout output.
- **For a given external program** that exhibits the problematic behavior at hand, it is **worth checking *if a different output character encoding can be requested***, such as via a *CLI parameter (option)* or an *environment variable*.

  - For instance, the `wsl.exe` CLI also outputs UTF-16LE by default for certain subcommands, but can be instructed to use UTF-8 by setting the `WSL_UTF8` environment variable (`$env:WSL_UTF8=1`); however, unless you're using `>` in 7.4+ or the output is all-ASCII, you'll still have to (temporarily) modify `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to set it to UTF-8 (`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`)

Comment: Wow, that is a truly awesome explanation, thank you so much! I really appreciate the effort! I gave it a try and it worked instantly! =)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped, @Fabster; my pleasure. Thanks for the nice feedback.